# shake css issue with translation of svg group

Tags: css, svg, vector, shake

I've got a bee that I am trying to animate its wings but for some reason they are translated to the top of the view box.

here's my pen:

```
http://codepen.io/vannygee/pen/BpqVeX
```

At first I thought this was the issue but idk..

```
display: inline-block;
transform-origin: center center;
```

Anyone familiar with shake-css?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GreenSock's blogpost about SVG transforms: https://greensock.com/svg-transforms

I believe the basic gist is that the translate property in some browsers is relative to the viewbox of the SVG rather than the element/path you're targeting. GSAP is my go-to solution for this because it turns the transforms into matrix transforms to compensate for this issue.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look
I notice that the wings in my file have a weird translation (and rotation). I didn't realise that if I rotated the file in sketch (flipped both vertically and horizontally) it would apply a translation. Perhaps i'll make it again from scratch, path to path

Comment: Looks like you're right. If you need wide browser support I'd look into GSAP but otherwise it looks like it is the transforms inherit in your SVG that are the problem.

Comment: all right so I looked into GSAP and I thought i'd see if it was my svgs fault, check out how funny this is:

http://codepen.io/vannygee/pen/bgmxeo

Comment: Yeah the SVG is definitely structured oddly and is the largest issue, but on the other hand look how much CSS you compacted into 3 lines of JS. (obviously requires the 3rd party library) but much more manageable animation. Good luck with the SVG!

Comment: Thanks again Alejalapeno i'm now planning a big animation so I need to think it out